# Virtual hosts on apache with URL's like subfolders

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, vhosts, ubuntu-server

I am interested in, if I can have vhosts on apache with domain names like:
**http://something.com/something** or **http://{server-ip-address-here}/something** ?

I am using Apache 2.2.20 on Ubuntu Server, thats my home server and I am testing some stuff here, I dont have any DNS server here and what I have is only public IP address and a domain name attached to it from open dns service.

So, what did I do:

1. I have created new file "demo" in **/etc/apache2/sites-available**
2. I put there this (actually it is copied  with modifications from default file):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      ServerName  {mydomain-here}/demo/
      DocumentRoot /vhosts/demo
   <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
   </Directory>
   <Directory /vhosts/demo/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride None
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
   </Directory>

   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
           AllowOverride None
           Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
   # alert, emerg.
   LogLevel warn

   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
   <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Created symlink in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ which points to /etc/apache2/sites-available/demo
4. Created **/vhosts/demo/index.html** file.

And now what i get is that when I go to {my-domain} I go to vhost which I have created, but problem is that server points me there in ANY case, not only {my-domain}/demo what I want.

In conclusion, I want that I can create different virtual hosts and attach them to different URL's which will have same base-url, for example www.mydomain.com/vhost1, www.mydomain.com/vhost2 etc..

Is it possible?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To start, the reason why it goes there is ANY case is cause you have you have a *:80 setting for your virtual host, so if nothing matches the request it uses the first virtual host entry

If I understand what you are trying to do it appears like you might just want to alias each 'virtual host'

What you are trying to do isn't quite a virtual host (at least what a virtual host is supposed to do), but you might be able to accomplish it by using alias feature of apache

```
Alias /vhost1 /whatever/folder/your/vhost1/site/is/at
Alias /vhost2 /whatever/folder/your/vhost2/site/is/at
```

So now whatever domain you use e.g. http://whatever.com/vhost1 or http://whatever.com/vhost2
The both of em will appear as separate sites

Comment: Thanks :) I created Aliases and I got exactly that result, which I wanted!

But, for interest:
It looks like that its not possible to make virtual hosts that way, is it?

Comment: I don't think so, I've never used it like that before.  Generally you use it when you need one server to be able to server files for multiple domains/ips e.g. www.vhost1.com and www.vhost2.com and using the virtual host is how the server knows what files to server www.vhost1.com and www.vhost2.com

Comment: in your case, there is only one domain so the virtual host isn't necessarily useful to differentiate your sites

Comment: Thank you dude :) I got what I wanted to get with aliases ;)

Comment: Hey guys, where exactly you are suppose to put above lines?

Comment: depends how you have your configurations setup.  If you wanna do it server wide, you could add it in the conf/httpd.conf file, or you can put it in your conf.d/vhost.conf (or whatever you call your extra virtual host config file) in the specific virtual host you are add these rules too